# Pylint invalid function name

Tags: python, pylint

I'm running Pylint 1.7.2 with Python 3.6.2. Pylint is showing the following error:

```
Invalid function name "create_maximization_option_dataframe" (invalid-name)
```

I define a function like so in my code:

```
def create_maximization_option_dataframe(file_name):
```

The PEP8 style guide basically just says:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

As far as I'm aware I'm following all the formatting rules for a function name. Does Pylint have some built-in maximum function name length rule that I'm not aware of? I can ignore the Pylint error easily enough but I want to understand why this is happening first.

Comment: Easy to test: if you put in a shorter name in the same format what happens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a config file by doing pylint `pylint --generate-rcfile`. The scope of that depends where you put it. Quoting https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html

1. pylintrc in the current working directory
2. .pylintrc in the
       current working directory
3. If the current working directory is in a
       Python module, Pylint searches up the hierarchy of Python modules
       until it finds a pylintrc file. This allows you to specify coding
       standards on a module-by-module basis. Of course, a directory is
       judged to be a Python module if it contains an **init**.py file.
4. The file named by environment variable PYLINTRC
5. if you have a home
           directory which isn’t /root:   .pylintrc in your home directory
           .config/pylintrc in your home directory
6. /etc/pylintrc

Sounds like you need option 5 or 6.

In the pylintrc, find this bit

```
# Regular expression matching correct function names
function-rgx=[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$
```

Change that 30 near the end to 40 or so.

Comment: I tried adding an empty pylintrc file to the project. But I get an error: configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers. Please can you add the header info to your answer?

Answer (score 7):

According to PyLint documentation, a function name must have from 2 to 30 characters. Yours has 36.

Comment: That documentation states: "Options can be used to override the default regular expression associated to each type." How can I globally override the function name length limit imposed by PyLint?

Comment: Check PyLint documentation, it has it all: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/options.html

Comment: Actually, I think it's 3 to 31 characters: `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$`. If you wanted 2 to 30, that would be `[a-z_][a-z0-9_]{1,29}$`