# Method name doesn't conform to snake_case naming style

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I’m creating a simple project with my pylintrc file and get this error for the test method:

```
method name - test_calculator_add_method_returns_correct_result -  doesn't conform to snake_case naming style
```

```py
class TddInPythonExample(unittest.TestCase):
    """ This is a basic test class"""

    def test_calculator_add_method_returns_correct_result(self):
        """ This test the calculator add method """
        calc = Calculator()
        result = calc.add(2,2)
        self.assertEqual(4, result)
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: its a warning, as shown on the subject.

Comment: This might be better as a bug report to pylint’s maintainers than an SO question; that method name does appear to have the right style. They’ll also probably want to see the config file in question.

Comment: even I thought the name appear to be in the right style, just want to confirm...will report a bug to pylint.thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Why is the method name rejected

It appears according to this: `(Link removed)` that the length of the name is capped at 30 characters, where your method name is 49 characters long

## The fix

You can shorten the method name, or change your config to allow longer methods

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893283/3527520 contains a note about how to do the config change

Comment: If you just want to specify an exception to the rule: # pylint: disable=invalid-name

Comment: The link in this answer points to what appears to be a Chinese language site so is not appropriate to be used in an answer for this site. The link itself also appears to be broken so even if it linked to a section in English that is no longer the case.

Answer (score 23):

If you are a Visual Studio Code user who wants to ignore this, you can add `python.linting.pylintArgs` to `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=C0103"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Very well pointed by @jrtapsell

## **To Add further information:**

There is a regular expression defined for each type when it comes to naming convention.

You may note the length of a name can vary from 2 to 30 characters along with its regex.

```
    +-------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
    |       Type        |    Option     |        Default regular expression         |
    +-------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
    | Argument          | argument-rgx  | [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$                    |
    | Attribute         | attr-rgx      | [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$                    |
    | Class             | class-rgx     | [A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]+$                       |
    | Constant          | const-rgx     | (([A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*)|(__.*__))$            |
    | Function          | function-rgx  | [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$                    |
    | Method            | method-rgx    | [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$                    |
    | Module            | module-rgx    | (([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)|([A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+))$ |
    | Variable          | variable-rgx  | [a-z_][a-z0-9_]{2,30}$                    |
    | Variable, inline1 | inlinevar-rgx | [A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$                   |
    +-------------------+---------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The link points to a Chinese Language only site which is not suitable for inclusion in an answer on this site.

Comment: Just FYI, the regular expression for the method name is actually 3-31 characters long. The first character, then 2-30 characters after that.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have not generated the .pylinrc file, you can do so using the following
command.

```
pylint --generate-rcfile | out-file -encoding utf8 .pylintrc
```

then you can change the type of naming case in .pylinrc file,
here are some popular cases and sample use case.

> 

PascalCase: NewObject
camelCase: newObject
PascalCase: LongFunctionName()
camelCase: longFunctionName()

Answer (score -1):

Note that line whenever you get this kind of error. you need to mention your function name in snake_case style.
That means

```
"def TddInPythonExample():": ->  def dd_in_python_example():
```